# Braces inside the array - postgresql

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql

I have a table "temp" with two attributes: integer, text[].

I would like to insert a record with the brace inside the array. 
For example a record like this:

```
1, {'1{c}1','a'}
```

where 1 is the integer and '1{c}1' is the first element of the array and 'a' the second element of the array.

I tried a simply insert like this:

```
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (id, '{'1{c}1','a'}');
```

but it says that is malformed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [PostgreSQL documentation for arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/arrays.html),

> You can put double quotes around any element value, and must do so if it contains commas or curly braces.

A correct syntax would like this:

```
INSERT INTO "temp" VALUES (1, '{"1{c}1",a}');
```

You can see a complete, working [example on SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/158dd/4).

Comment: You could also use the `array['1{c}1', 'a']` notation for the array, fewer quoting hassles that way.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition, it's also possible to use array constructors, I think it's more safe to use, because array elements are just SQL constants and you also could use expressions inside the array constructors:

```
insert into "temp" values(1, array['1{c}1','a']);
```

it's clear that this is array of strings, and this too

```
insert into "temp" values(1, array['1','2']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want those inner single quotes.

```
INSERT INTO temp VALUES (id, '{1{c}1,a}');
```